# Merge multiple database results into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am unsure as to what to call this question. I have been thinking a lot about it, and I do not think that what I've chosen covers it adequately, but it was the best I could manage. Forgive me if it is very misleading or incorrect.

I am creating a small CMS for personal use, but I have stumbled upon trouble.

The information is stored in a MySQL database, and the table has three columns: *cid*, *page* and *cont*.

The cid is the identifier of a certain piece of content. If a *page* has multiple pieces of content, such as a main area of text and a sub area of text, the *cid* on these rows would be different, but the *page* would be the same, seeing as the content is on the same page.

On the index page of the CMS I am then displaying all the different pages that exist in the database, as links. The user then clicks the link to the page on which he'd want to change the  content.

**Now, here is my issue:**

When displaying the data from the database, rows that have the same page, but different *cid* is, logically, displayed as separate links.

That sounded confusing. I'll say it differently:

**What I need is that** if a result has the same *page* as another result, these two are merged together into one link, and not displayed as two separate links.

This is how the database looks:

```
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+                                                                           
| cid        | page     | cont                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+  
| page1-main | page1    | This is the first page on this website! |        
| page2-main | page2    | This is the second page!                |                                                                                                                                 
| page2-sub  | page2    | This is sub-content!                    |                                                                  
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

As I said, what I want is to have any rows that have the same *page* be merged into one result in my while loop, because what happens now is that they are separated into two different results. This is my loop and query:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM content");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   ?>
     <a href="edit.php?p=<?php echo $row['page'];?>">Link!</a>
   <?php
  }
```

That will, of course, display two results, even though they have the same page. I am unsure as to whether it is some PHP I will have to do, or it is in the MySQL query. I am a good bit unexperienced in SQL, but fairly experienced in PHP.

I've been thinking about some ifs. Like, storing every new result that is displayed in a variable and then comparing them, and if one that has occurred before occurs again, then it is not displayed, or something. But I don't know.

It would be wonderful if anyone could help me out here.

Comment: try doing SELECT * FROM content group by page

Comment: For improved performance, if you only need the `page` column, then ditch the "`*`" in your query, and reference just the columns you need to return. To have the rows returned in a deterministic sequence, include an ORDER BY in your query. `SELECT DISTINCT page FROM content ORDER BY page`. (A `GROUP BY` in MySQL implicitly performs an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> what I want is to have any rows that have the same page
> be merged into one result
```

You can use GROUP BY to merge them:

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM content GROUP BY page");

Answer (score 0):

These queries will return an equivalent result:

```
SELECT page FROM content GROUP BY page;

SELECT DISTINCT page FROM content ORDER BY page;
```

If you don't need to return columns other than `page`, then replace the `*` in your query (which is shorthand for "all columns", and instead reference just the columns that you actually need returned.)